# Yammer REST API @mentions in Message posting

Tags: yammer

Yammer message posting with @mention in the body enables that person to involve in a conversation even he is not in that private group. But when doing this through REST API, that person is able to see the message only if he is already in the private group. Anyone has overcome this?

Comment: There is some new functionality being tested at the moment that enables the first behaviour that you describe. This is only available through Yammer apps at the moment, and the website. If this feature is launched then the API may change to support it. I'm making requests internally about this.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Hope Yammer will change the API soon to support it.

Comment: @BrianLyttle Has there been any movement on this functionality?

Comment: @Wex mentioning a user should include them in that conversation today. Try mentioning a user on a thread in the Yammer Web App and you'll see a warning about adding the user. Is this failing for you with the REST API?